# Disable javascript like media query

Tags: javascript

I have a script that rotate my div, but i want to disable the js when i my screen be less than 600px, this is the code that rotate the div:

```
var form = document.getElementById('survey-form');

form.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) =>{
    var x = (window.innerWidth / 2 - e.pageX) / 200;
    var y = (window.innerHeight / 2 - e.pageY) / 200;

    form.style.transform = 'rotateX(' + x + 'deg) rotateY(' + y + 'deg)'
});

form.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    form.style.transform = 'rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg)';
});
```

And I alright tried this

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width()>600){
    var form = document.getElementById('survey-form');

form.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) =>{
    var x = (window.innerWidth / 2 - e.pageX) / 200;
    var y = (window.innerHeight / 2 - e.pageY) / 200;

    form.style.transform = 'rotateX(' + x + 'deg) rotateY(' + y + 'deg)'
});

form.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    form.style.transform = 'rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg)';
});
}
```

But the code just stop working on all screens.

Comment: each time you resize you do check for the width and attach an event listener, and this listener will be there and executed till you remove it. that s a first thing.  anyway unless you remove it. on dom ready add your event listener once, and check inside the callback the actual width

Answer (score 3):

It stops because you're checking `$(window).width()>600`. That means if screen width is **greater** then **600px** and you're looking to target screen which is **less** then 600px. So simply just switch this `$(window).width() > 600` to this `$(window).width() < 600`